# How to show a drop down menu when click on link jquery

Tags: jquery

i know how to trap a click event on any link. here is my code

```
<a id="piclink_1" class="picLinks">...</a>

$('a.picLinks').click(function() {
    //split at the '_' and take the second offset
    var picNumber = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]; 
    viewer.show(picNumber);
});
```

i want to show a drop down menu which will appear with two sub menu just below the link when i will click on the link. and also if i click outside of that link of drop down menu then drow down menu will hide.please guide me how can i achieve this. thanks

### my markup look like

```
<a id="link">About</a>

<div id="submenu">
     <a href="#">About the company</a><br />
     <a href="#">Careers</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the markup that you'd like to use? You will be showing or hiding the drop down, just like you do with the viewer.

Comment: google it? e.g. http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: What is `viewer`? You need to provide more markup.

Comment: A JSFiddle is always helpful too.

Comment: http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-jquery-drop-down-menu-in-3-simple-steps/
http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/simple-drop-down-menu-with-jquery-and.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $('a.picLinks').click(function() {
    $('#submenu').show();    
 });

 var mouseIn = false;   

    $('a.picLinks').click(function() {

     $('#submenu').hover(function(){ 
        mouseIn =true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouseIn =false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
        if( mouseIn == false)
         $('#submenu').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: i want to show the menu just below the link.so i have to set left & top dynamically based on the position of link. but there is no code for positioning in ur code.